# What is the structure of Field No. 54 (P54) in the the ISO 8583 Standard

Tags: iso8583

What is the structure of Field (P54) in the ISO 8583 Standard?

This field is about of the balance Amount that sent by the switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of the types of accounts and amount types and the conditions in which they are allowed vary by each instance and variation of ISO-8583 but the standard format is the following:

The data element breakdown, occurring up to six times for a total length up to a total length of 120.

- Position Data 1-2
- Account Type (n 2) 3-4  *(Must match DE003 format)*
- Amount Type (An 2) 5-7  *(See Table Below for a sample of SOME of the values)*
- Currency Code (n 3) 8-20 *(ISO-3166-1 Numeric, just like DE049-DE051)*
- Amount (x + n 12)

The amount must not be greater than 999999999. 
"X" must be 0, C, or D. C or 0 = Credit amount and D = Debit Amount

Some of Amount Types others really vary by specification and though these are all numeric the Healthcare transactions are AlphaNumeric values in the VISA specification for example. Note that most of these are actually not commonly used in PIN or Debit transactions except 01, 02, 40-43, 57, 58, and 91.

ISO Code Description

- 00 Unknown
- 01 Account ledger balance
- 02 Account available balance
- 03 Amount owing
- 04 Amount due
- 05 Available Credit Line
- 06-10 Reserved for ISO use
- 11-15 Reserved for national use
- 16 Credit line
- 17 POS balance
- 18-19 Reserved for private use
- 20 Amount remaining this cycle
- 21-30 Reserved for ISO use
- 31-35 Reserved for national use
- 36-39 Reserved for private use
- 40 Amount Cash / Cash Back / Negotiable Item including Scrip
- 41 Amount goods and services
- 42 Amount Check (Deposit Only)
- 43 Amount Cash (Deposit Only)
- 42-50 Reserved for ISO use
- 51-55 Reserved for national use
- 56 Hold amount
- 57 Pre-Authorized Amount.
- 58 Authorized amount. (Used for Response Code DE039 = 10 Authorized for
  a Different Amount)
- 59 Floor Limit
- 60-79 Reserved for ISO use
- 80-89 Reserved for national use
- 91 Originally Requested Amount transaction in the currency amount of DE049.
- 92-93 Reserved for private use

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Christopher

Comment: hi, in a sample of response from switch this field is contain two amount and two string include of special value (for example National Unit Code), what are these value exactly? are these value a internal standard?

Comment: @class1234 There can be up to 6 independent strings in the response from the switch. I am assuming when you state "National Unit Code" (which I have not heard that term before in this context) you mean currency code. Such as US Dollars vs. the British Pound vs. the Yen. That is the ISO-3166-1 numeric standard. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric); which the complete list can be found multiple places including its Wikipedia article. The other fields in the string are also referred to above being the Account Type (which matches DE003) & Amount type which I dumped above.

Comment: @class1234 I believe I have answered your question in some detail, I would appreciate you accepting the answer as per the community guidelines.

Comment: @CRSouser Is it for both 1987 and 1993 version?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Yes for 87, 93, and most post 93 variants.

Comment: @CRSouser Should amount field (4) be added in Balance Inquiry?